# Приложение обратилось к интерфейсу, относящемуся к другому потоку

Tags: c#, многопоточность, xaml, uwp

У меня есть класс, содержащий делегаты

```
static public class ClientEvents
    {
        public delegate void TimeOutServer();
        public delegate void TimeOut();
        public static BTimeOut.TimeOutMethod timeOutConnect;
        public static BTimeOut.TimeOutMethod timeOutMessage;
        public static BTimeOut.TimeOutMethod ConnectEvent;
    }
```

Эти функции вызываются при определенных событиях. Например, функция ConnectEvent вызывается при успешном соединении с сервером.

```
public WelcomePage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            StaticApp sa = new StaticApp();//запускается клиент
            ClientEvents.ConnectEvent = Connect;//сработает при успешном коннекте с сервером
        }
        void Connect()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("CONNECT EVENT");
            ConnectTitle.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Form.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

СonnectTitle и Form это некие элементы интерфейса. Но я получаю ошибку:

> Приложение обратилось к интерфейсу, относящемуся к другому потоку.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

Функция, в которой и вызывается делегат:

```
 private bool Connectorlastfirst(Json j, IPEndPoint ipep)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("CONNECTORLAST");
            if (connectTable.table.ContainsKey(ipep.ToString()))
            {
                var uConnectData = connectTable.table[ipep.ToString()];
                bTimeOut.Remove("timeout first connect to " + ipep.ToString());
                Conteiners.DHCase data = Serializer.Deserialize<Conteiners.DHCase>(j.obj);
                var uData = new Conteiners.UserData();
                uData.hash = data.Hash;
                uData.DH = uConnectData.DH;
                uData.pKey = data.publicKey;
                uData.port = uConnectData.port;
                uData.ip = uConnectData.ip;
                uData.connectFlag = true;
                if (userTable.table.ContainsKey(uData.hash))
                    userTable.table.Remove(uData.hash);
                userTable.table.Add(uData.hash, uData);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            ClientEvents.ConnectEvent();//вызов
            return true;
        }
```

Эта функция входит сюда:

```
private void ParseReceive(Json data, IPEndPoint ipep)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("JSON TYPE " + data.type);
            if (data.type == 1)
            {
                ConnectorSecond(data, ipep, ClientEvents.timeOutConnect);
            }
            else if (data.type == (float)1.1)
            {
                Connectorlastfirst(data, ipep) ;
            }
            //Debug.WriteLine("JSON TYPE " + data.type);
        }
```

Последняя вызывается в Receive:

```
private Json Receive()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Receive");
            Json response = null;
            //flag = "Operation Timeout";
            // We are receiving over an established socket connection
            if (listener != null)
            {
                // Create SocketAsyncEventArgs context object
                SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT);
                // Setup the buffer to receive the data
                socketEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE], 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
                // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
                // Note: This even handler was implemented inline in order to make this method self-contained.
                string f = "";
                socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate (object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                    {
                        // Retrieve the data from the buffer
                        try
                        {
                            var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
                            str = str.Trim('\0');
                            response = Serializer.Deserialize<Json>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
                            IPEndPoint ipep = (IPEndPoint)e.RemoteEndPoint;
                            Debug.WriteLine(ipep.ToString());
                            ParseReceive(response, ipep);
                            Receive();
                        }
                        catch (Exception obj)
                        {
                            f = "Can't deserialze receive data ";
                            Debug.WriteLine(f + obj.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response = null;
                    }
                    _clientDone.Set();
                });
                // Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block
                _clientDone.Reset();
                // Make an asynchronous Receive request over the socket
                listener.ReceiveFromAsync(socketEventArg);
                // Block the UI thread for a maximum of TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS milliseconds.
                // If no response comes back within this time then proceed
                //if(TimeOut!=0)
                // _clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
            }
            else
            {
                response = null;
                //    flag = "Invalid main socket";
            }

            return response;
        }
```

> Вызвано исключение: "System.Exception" в App5.exe System.Exception:
>   Приложение обратилось к интерфейсу, относящемуся к другому потоку.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))    at
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.put_Visibility(Visibility value)    at
>   App5.WelcomePage.Connect()    at
>   App5.Class.Client.Connectorlastfirst(Json j, IPEndPoint ipep)
>   Приложение обратилось к интерфейсу, относящемуся к другому потоку.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Подробности исключения и стек трейс в студию.

Comment: Я, вроде, все описал. Что такое " стек трейс" не знаю =(

Comment: Ну, это поле Stacktrace в исключении. Например, если вы ловите исключение, то в объекте-исключении оно есть. Или оно выводится, если вывести исключение на консоль (через `.ToString()`).

Answer (score 2):

```
async void ConnectGo() {
            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("CONNECT EVENT");
                ConnectTitle.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                Form.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            });
```

Как-то так

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, `Connect` вызывается вне UI-потока. Вы должны перенаправить выполнение в нужный поток. Например, так:

```
void Connect()
{
    this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("CONNECT EVENT");
            ConnectTitle.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Form.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        });
}
```

Comment: Dispatcher не содержит InvokeAsync. Обратите внимание на теги. Речь идет про UWP

Comment: не смотря на то, что Ваш ответ не совсем верен, он навел меня на нужный ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: @SanychGoilo: А, перепутал с WPF.